# Problems with newest Firebase Update (iOS, CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoa, firebase-realtime-database, leveldb

I updated Firebase through pod update to Version: 4.8.0

XCode Version: 9.1
Language: Objective-C

Since that only weird things are happening in my Xcode:

"Lexical or Preprocessor Issue"
- I get a 'string' file not found , slice.h and

"Parse Issue"
- Could not build Objective-C module 'Core Foundation'

I cannot get around this issue

- I updated CocoaPods
- reinstalled Firebase
- tried to add Frameworks manually
- changing around build settings
  (installing old Firebase version makes the errors go away, but that's of course not my intention)

What's wrong here? Is there something wrong with leveldb?

Would be glad to receive any help!

Comment: did you delete your pod folder and do pod install again? also clean your project with shift + cmd + k

Comment: Yes I did both, also cleaned DerivedData manually, the project still fails to execute because of the same errors :(

Comment: same problem here Xcode 9 / swift4. reverted to firebase 4.0.2 and now compiles fine.

Comment: for those who could need : specify the version like that : pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.0.2'

Comment: UPDATE: It's August now and the latest version (5.4.1) of Firebase/Core will still not compile for the same reason.

Comment: Still the same problem for version 5.10.0 -> October.